# SSH issue - Disconnecting: Received data for nonexistent channel 0

Tags: ssh, redhat, sftp

The log below is from SSHD server when SSH client is trying to connect. I'm sure that I have correct ssh key. I just compared two RHEL5 servers. As I red, this means that server closed the connection for some reason. But any suggestions how to try to solve the issue and find the root cause?

```
Jul 29 20:12:11 sshd[13259]: subsystem request for sftp
Jul 29 20:12:11 sshd[13259]: channel_by_id: 0: bad id: channel free
Jul 29 20:12:11 sshd[13259]: Disconnecting: Received data for nonexistent channel 0.
```

OS: RHEL 5.11,
SSHD service: default

Comment: What SSH client are you using?

Comment: It's Jenkins 1.642.2.1 ssh client which works well with RHEL 5.11 other hosts. Jenkins configuration is very simple and the same for all nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The error message `Disconnecting: Received data for nonexistent channel 0.` might be caused by incorrect sshd configuration.

Check if the line `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` (or similar) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` points to the correct binary.

Another cause for the error could be an incorrect setting `system shell` setting in `/etc/passwd` for the user. [source](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/317873/)

Comment: Thanks for ideas. In my case, it doesn't help. `/etc/passwd` has identical entry and `sshd_config` has no differences between successful and failed host. sftp parameter is `Subsystem sftp /opt/quest/libexec/sftp-server` which could be the issue even if one host is successful with that. I'm not sure how to test/debug this sftp-server separately from SSHD service.

Comment: I would try to disable sftp server by commenting `# Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` and restarting the ssh server. If you are lucky Jenkins will fall back to scp.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error because the server was out of disk space. Deleting some large files solved the issue and I was able to SFTP files to it again.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait
```

Or

```
/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait
```

I was looking for a solution to reduce the amount of XXX_WAIT on my server

```
[mihamina@RKTMB ~]$ sudo ss -taupen | grep WAIT
tcp    TIME-WAIT  0      0      127.0.0.1:3128               127.0.0.1:60036               timer:(timewait,15sec,0) ino:0 sk:ffff9bbf5ba65000
tcp    TIME-WAIT  0      0      127.0.0.1:3128               127.0.0.1:60024               timer:(timewait,1.420ms,0) ino:0 sk:ffff9bbee4aa2300
tcp    TIME-WAIT  0      0      127.0.0.1:59994              127.0.0.1:3128                timer:(timewait,54sec,0) ino:0 sk:ffff9bbf5ba64c00
tcp    TIME-WAIT  0      0      127.0.0.1:60028              127.0.0.1:3128                timer:(timewait,2.467ms,0) ino:0 sk:ffff9bbee4aa2600
tcp    TIME-WAIT  0      0      127.0.0.1:59946              127.0.0.1:3128                timer:(timewait,23sec,0) ino:0 sk:ffff9bbf5ba65900
tcp    TIME-WAIT  0      0      127.0.0.1:3128               127.0.0.1:60032               timer:(timewait,7.045ms,0) ino:0 sk:ffff9bbee4aa2800
tcp    TIME-WAIT  0      0      127.0.0.1:60030              127.0.0.1:3128                timer:(timewait,5.521ms,0) ino:0 sk:ffff9bbee4aa2a00
 ... # I have a Loooooottt
```

And I found https://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning/

But if you read carefully, they warn about packets mess...

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle Linux 8 the reason for this message was an expired user password.
We configured `user1` to SFTP-only access, and when we tried to access SFTP-share using the private key for this `user1` we got the same error.
For Oracle Linux 8 you could check password expire using the command:

```
# chage -l user1
```

Look at the Password expires row. After we changed the password, we got a working account.

Answer (score -1):

Received SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA for nonexistent channel 0 winscp

El problema ocurre porque está llena la partición donde se intenta subir el archivo.
Un saludo.